# PHPを使ってテーブルにデータを追加する

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, mamp

phpを使ってphpmyadminのテーブルにデータを追加する方法ですが、
細かくは回答して頂かなくて結構なのですが、全体的な流れだけを
ご回答下さいませんか。

■mampでphpmyadminに接続してデータベース"personal"とテーブル"friend"を作成しましたので、PHPを使ってテーブル"friend"にデータを追加したいです。
PDOってものを使うのでしょうか。

お手すきの際で結構ですので、ご確認頂けると幸いです。

宜しくお願いします。

Comment: 前の質問は解決いたしましたか？解決した場合は解決した回答を承認するか、無い場合は自己回答して後日承認してください。また、`phpmyadmin`の使い方を知りたいのか、`MySQL`などの`データベース`へ`php`から接続したいのか分かりません。どう言ったことをしたいのでしょうか？`phpMyAdmin`は命令でもサービスでもなくツールでしかありません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。MySQLなどのデータベースへphpから接続したいです。宜しくお願いします。

Comment: 他の質問もそうですが、単に使い方を知りたいならまずは公式のドキュメントや解説サイトなどを参照してください。実際に何か試したうえで上手くいかない・分からない部分が出てきた時点で質問しましょう。

Comment: @アフロ `phpMyAdmin`を勘違いしておりませんか？この質問に`phpMyAdmin`は関係ないかと思うのですが……。`phpMyAdmin`はデータベースを提供はしていませんよ？

Answer (score 1):

ここで質問する前に、まず以下のURL等のチュートリアルを最初から最後までやってみるべきだと思います。

https://www.phpbook.jp/tutorial/mysql/

この質問では範囲が広すぎて、ここでは回答しきれないと思います。
チュートリアルをやってみて、わからないところがあれば、ピンポイントで質問してください。